# loadtest throwing error even after successful connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, load-testing

Below is a simple code which i have written to test loadtest module

```
let express = require("express")
let loadtest = require('loadtest')

let app = express()

app.get("/first",(req,res)=>
{  
    let total = 0
    for(i=0;i<50_000_000;i++)
    {
        total++
    }
    
    res.send(`We are alright with ${total}`)
})

app.all("*",(req,res)=>
{
    res.send("This is Commong path")
})

app.listen(6500,()=>
{
    console.log(`We are listening on 6500 & id is ${process.pid}` )
    
    // Start load test after server is listening
    loadtest.loadTest({
        url: 'http://localhost:6500/first',
        concurrency: 10, // Number of concurrent requests
        maxRequests: 1000, // Total number of requests to send
    }, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Load test failed:', error)
        } else {
            console.log('Load test completed:', result)
        }
    })
})
```

It is a simple programme intended to check `loadtest` . But upon running it , I got below error

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ENOTCONN
    at tryReadStart (node:net:680:20)
    at Socket._read (node:net:691:5)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:12)
    at Socket.read (node:net:747:39)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:999:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4053,
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Now as evident from the pricture , I am getting connection successful message , then why this message is showing , and how to resolve it ?
[image]